# chartjs: set default min for the line chart

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a line chart which is drawing at its default min. I have changed the min of the chart on the button click and then update it. Problem is i want to toggle on the button click. Like if i have set the min on the button click. by clicking again it should change again back to the normal min. But in that it did not have a min at all in the default case.

I am setting this like

```
$('#action').off().on('click', function() {
    myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = -50;
    myLineChart.update();
})
```

This is my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycoaLxye/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};
var option = {
  legend: false,
  title: {
    display: true,
  }
};

var myLineChart = Chart.Line('myChart', {
  data: data,
  options: option
});

$('#action').off().on('click', function() {
        myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = -50;
        myLineChart.update();

        $("#action2").show();
        $("#action").hide();
    })
$('#action2').off().on('click', function() {
    myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 0;
    myLineChart.update();

    $("#action").show();
    $("#action2").hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<button id="action" style="display: block;">action</button>
<button id="action2" style="display: none;">action</button>
```

**You can split the task by adding another button.**

Please Add one more button on HTML with same name but display none.

```
<button id="action" style="display: block;">action</button>
<button id="action2" style="display: none;">action</button>
```

Add one More function

```
$('#action').off().on('click', function() {
        myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = -50;
        myLineChart.update();

        $("#action2").show();
        $("#action").hide();
    })
$('#action2').off().on('click', function() {
    myLineChart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 0;
    myLineChart.update();

    $("#action").show();
    $("#action2").hide();
})
```

OnClick you can hide / show (toggle)

Comment: actually i want toggle and other thing is i dont want to start with the `min=0`. it should be the default value.

Comment: You can pass the value by onclick function. or dataset min value.

Comment: you are not understanding this is not about javascript this about the chart.js. Because chartjs automatically set the default if not any min or max is specified.